# java create variable from regex findings

Tags: java, regex

I'm pretty new to Java, but I am looking to create a String variable from a regex finding. But I am not too sure how.

Basically I need: `previous_identifer = (all the text in nextline up to the third comma);`

Something maybe like this?

```
previous_identifier = line.split("^(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),");
```

Or:

```
line = reader.readLine();
Pattern courseColumnPattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),");
previous_identifier = (courseColumnPattern.matcher(line).find());
```

But I know that won't work. What should I do differently?

Comment: Heya! Just to confirm, are you looking to get a String at the end of the day, or an array of Strings that happen to be the first three?

Comment: Just a String, that holds text up to the third comma. Thanks!

Comment: Alrighty. As I'm writing my answer, I'll say that I'm going with your first approach, using [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split).

Comment: why use split to find a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split) to return an array of Strings, then use a StringBuilder to build your return string. An advantage of this approach is being able to easily return the first four strings, two strings, ten strings, etc.

```
int limit = 3, current = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Used as an example of input
String str = "test,west,best,zest,jest";

String[] strings = str.split(",");

for(String s : strings) {
    if(++current > limit) {
        // We've reached the limit; bail
        break;
    }
    if(current > 1) {
        // Add a comma if it's not the first element. Alternative is to
        // append a comma each time after appending s and remove the last
        // character

        sb.append(",");
    }

    sb.append(s);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // Prints "test,west,best"
```

If you don't need to use the three elements separately (you truly want just the first three elements in a chunk), you can use a Matcher with the following regular expression:

```
String str = "test, west, best, zest, jest";

// Matches against "non-commas", then a comma, then "non-commas", then 
// a comma, then "non-commas". This way, you still don't have a trailing
// comma at the end.
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)").matcher(str);

if(match.find())
{
    // Print out the output!
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
else
{
    // We didn't have a match. Handle it here.
}
```

Comment: he asked how to use regex.

Comment: @CharlieS: He asked how to create a String from the first three comma-separated values in a line. Technically, it even uses a regular expression (String.split takes in a regular expression). At the end of the day, this solves the problem.

Comment: Title of this question is "java create variable from regex findings"

Comment: @CharlieS: And my regex is ",". I'm using the results differently though. Working on a more "traditional" solution that gets the first three values though.

Comment: @CharlieS: Edited to include a second solution that uses a matcher instead of split.

Answer (score -1):

try an online regex tester to work out the regex, i think you need less brackets to get the entire text, i'd guess something like:

```
([^,+?],[^,+?],[^,+?])
```

Which says, find everything except a comma, then a comma, then everything but a comma, then a comman, then everything else that isn't a comma. I suspect this can be improved dramatically, i am not a regex expert

Then your java just needs to compile it and match against your string:

```
line = reader.readLine();
Pattern courseColumnPattern = Pattern.compile("([^,+?],[^,+?],[^,+?])");
if (previous_identifier.matches()) {
    previous_identifier = (courseColumnPattern.matcher(line);
}
```

Comment: Why are you excluding `?` and `+`?

Answer (score -1):

Your regex will work, but could be expressed more briefly. This is how you can "extract" it:

```
String head = str.replaceAll("((.+?,){3}).*", "$1");
```

This matches the whole string, while capturing the target, with the replacement being the captured input using a back reference to group 1.

---

Despite the downvote, here's proof the code works!

```
String str = "foo,bar,baz,other,stuff";
String head = str.replaceAll("((.+?,){3}).*", "$1");
System.out.println(head);
```

Output:

```
foo,bar,baz,
```